# Injecting environment variables to a React application when serving it with an express server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm developing an app that has the backend and frontend as part of a single project and the backend, aside from being the API, it also serves the static files for the frontend by doing this:

```
const frontendDir = appRoot.resolve("../frontend/build")
app.use(express.static(frontendDir))
app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(frontendDir, "index.html")))
```

Is there a way to somehow pre-process those files before sending them to inject some of the environment variables the server has access to but the client obviously doesn't?

I'm trying to make some variables accessible, like `SENTRY_DSN`, `HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION`, `HEROKU_RELEASE_CREATED_AT`, etc.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this would help but I think you could use a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) for passing your data to the front end  .like handlebars :

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')

Handlebars.registerHelper('prod', () => {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
})
```

in your html file:

```
<div class="some-content">   
  {{#if prod}}
    <p>Seen only in production</p>
  {{/if}}
  
  <p>This is some example text</p>
</div>
```